# Time complexity of exponentiation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
 int aux(int n, int x) {
    while (x < n) {
        x *= x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

---

```
int func(int n) {
    return aux(n, 2);
}
```

why is the time complexity of the `func` function is `O(log(log(n)))`?

Comment: It's not. If n >= 2 it is O(1) and if n < 2 the code exhibits undefined behavior when `x` overflows.

Comment: Are you sure of what you wrote? A call to func(1) will never stop, because 1<2...

Comment: yes, its from a test from last year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `x` starts from `2` and we square at each step, it follows the following sequence:

```
2^(2^0), 2^(2^1), 2^(2^2), ..., 2^(2^k), 2^(2^k) * 2^(2^k) = 2^(2^(k + 1)) ...
```

The loop continues as long as `2^(2^k) <= n` => `2^k <= log(n)` => `k <= log(log(n))`

Comment: Assuming `while (x < n)` was intended.

Comment: Always... Sometimes we have to guess

Comment: thx! how did you get this formula? i mean how did you know that its equal to 2^(2^k)?

Comment: In iteration 0 x is 2, in iteration 1 2, in iteration `k` you can prove by induction that is equal to `2^(2^k)`. That's why i included the induction step: `2^(2^k) * 2^(2^k) = 2^(2^(k + 1))`